# Output broken when appending output of sql query in ksh

Tags: shell-script, ksh, variable, command-substitution, sql

I'm very new to scripting. I would like to add the output of the sql function given below to another variable for example:

```
month_end ()
{
mdate=$($SQLPLUS_HOME/sqlplus.exe -S $DBC  << END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
select to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),'yyyymmdd') from dual;
exit;
END
)
}
```

when I echo the output from $mdate is perfect. (20160531)

But when I append to another varable, the whole value is broken ( _WORLD.txt instead of Hello_20160531_WORLD.txt).

```
FILENAME=Hello
EXTENSION=WORLD.txt
NAME=$FILENAME_${mdate}_${EXTENSION}

echo ${NAME}
```

Comment: you need to quote your variables.  e.g.  `NAME="$FILENAME_${mdate}_${EXTENSION}"` and `echo "$NAME"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because underscore `_` is a valid part of a variable name, so you also need the curly braces around `FILENAME`:

```
NAME=${FILENAME}_${mdate}_${EXTENSION}
```

Based on your other response, it appears that you also have a carriage return (`\r`) in either the FILENAME assignment line or the output of sqlplus, in `$mdate`. Find out which by running `cat -v` on your shell script, and/or doing `echo $mdate | cat -v`. Since I just noticed the sqlplus.*exe*, I assume you're running in a Cygwin-like environment, which may be adding the carriage return. Fix it by adding `mdate=${mdate//^M/}` where you enter ^M by typing control-v, control-m.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this forum as well.

Comment: thanks for your immediate response, I just tried your sugeestion, but am getting another broken output (_WORLD.txt0531)

Please let me know whats happening and how I can solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Jeff, I tried to work with your solution. But when I'm tryig to use ctrl v and ctrl m, it is treating ctrl v as paste option and ctrl m as new line. So I'm not getting expected result. Am I doing something wrong? Please help me..

Comment: in my case, I have outputed the value to a text file, trimed the carraige return '\r' with tr -d command andwritten to another variable